# How to fix htaccess with and without trailing slash

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I am facing a very little problem, when i browse site without trailing slash it works fine but when i add trailing slash in the end it redirect me to 404 page

e.g.

> mysite.com/category/slug-name/page/3/
>
> mysite.com/category/slug-name/page/5/

works fine but when i click page 1 it that has a trailing slash i.e.

> mysite.com/category/slug-name/

it gives error but without trailing slash it works fine for me

Similarly on articles page when i access without trailing slash it works but when i add trailing slash in the end, It redirects me to 404 page e.g. when i access this URL it works fine

> mysite.com/123-article-slug-here

but in this case I got 404 error

> mysite.com/123-article-slug-here/

I am sure that there is a problem in my htaccess but know how to fix it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/page/(.+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ article.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either removing the `/` from the slug name regex grouping or make that match non-greedy:

Remove `/` from grouping:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/page/(.+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ article.php?url=$1
```

Make non-greedy:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+?)/page/(.+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+?)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+?)/?$ article.php?url=$1
```

What's probably happening is that the `/` is getting matched inside the grouping (the parens) and that is getting passed to your `category.php`, and it doesn't like the `/` so returns a 404.

Comment: Awesome Non-greedy works for me thanks but can you please tell me what is the difference between removing / from grouping and non-greedy

Comment: @Brajman Removing the `/` from the grouping means you **can't** have `/` in your slug names, so: `/category/this/is/my-slug/` won't work. But if you make the match non-greedy, you can still match the `/` but it just won't match the *optional slash at the end*.

Comment: Oh thats a great info for me. Really really Thanks once again